# Retrieving NSArray From an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to get an array full of my data, I keep getting an BAD_ACCESS error when I run this though at the calling the array which I have not included here but I even commented that code out and tried just calling it to the log and still get the BAD_ACCESS error. The array is stored in a dictionary that contains a one key that is a number. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
ISData *is = [[ISData alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dic = [is getData:@"right" : isNumber];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dic valueForKey:@"2"]];

NSString *out = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

How the dictionary is created:

```
NSNumber* key = [NSNumber numberWithInt:isNumber];
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name], [NSString stringWithUTF8String:desc], [NSString stringWithUTF8String:intent], nil];

[dic setObject:values forKey:key];
```

Comment: `NSDictionary *dic = [is getData:@"right" : isNumber];` what on earth is that line supposed to be doing?  As far as I know, that isn't at all valid syntax

Comment: I don't know what ISData is...

Comment: @DanF: That's valid syntax. Arguments don't require names in ObjC. This selector looks like `-getData::`. It's non-idiomatic in modern ObjC though, except in unusual niche uses.

Comment: @quixoto I didn't know you could declare methods that way

Comment: First thing to do is to NSLog your dictionary.

Comment: _Where_ does your error happen? What are `isNumber`, `name`, `desc`, `intent`? Are you sure that all the various objects you're creating are valid and have the values you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say exactly where it crashes, and you don't have an obvious crashing bug here, so it's hard to diagnose your actual issue. This could be a memory management thing that's outside the code you've presented. But a couple things are going on here that are suspicious:

1. You should never have a bare `[MyClass alloc]` without the `-init` call. Your init should call super's init, which is responsible for setting up the new object.
2. Your `-valueForKey:` should be `-objectForKey:`. The difference is probably unimportant in this case, but the former is used for "KVC" coding, which you're not using. If you set it as object, get it as object.
3. Your `@"2"` as the key into the dictionary doesn't match your input, which is an NSNumber. NSNumbers are not string versions of numbers, so you're unlikely to find any value there. Instead, use the same `[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]` pattern.

Comment: This was hand typed out so I forgot to type the init, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that your array is empty. You can try print `NSLog(@"count = %d", array.count);` to see if that's the case.

If your `dic` is set up in the second block of code, then what's that `NSDictionary *dic = [is getData:...]` thing in the first block?

And is there a reason you cannot set up your array directly? Is there a reason for you to use a dictionary when it has only one key?